# writing a dictionary into a file

Tags: python, file, dictionary, text-files

I have a game board set up that gets certain values that are given to it. In the end the board is going to get filled up with the values. I want to write that final board into txt file. everytime I try it, it prints out the gameboard like this     [" ", "x", "o", " ", "x", " ", " ", "x", " "]. but I want it to print inside the actual board!

```
gameboard = [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]

def drawBoard(gameboard):
    print("    " "a" "   " "b" "   " "c")
    print("  ""-------------")
    print(("1"),("|"),gameboard[0],"|",gameboard[1], "|" ,gameboard[2], "|")
    print("  ""-------------")
    print(("2"),("|"),gameboard[3],"|",gameboard[4], "|" ,gameboard[5], "|")
    print("  ""-------------")   
    print(("3"),("|"),gameboard[6],"|",gameboard[7], "|" ,gameboard[8], "|")
    print("  ""-------------")
    return gameboard


def writeFinal(gameboard,filename):
    y= str(drawBoard(gameboard))
    filename.write(y)
    filename.close()

filename = open("final.txt", "w")

writeFinal(gameboard,filename):
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are just printing the game board to the screen and writing the default string interpretation of the list to the file.  You should have your drawBoard method return the string that is being printed, rather than the gameboard data itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your drawBoard does return the unmodified input parameter, a list, not the result of print statements, which get to the console.

Perhaps you should do something like this (not tested):

```
def getBoard(gameboard):
    linesep = '  -------------\n'
    res = linsep.join([
        '    a   b   c',
        '1 | %s | %s | %s |' % gameboard[0:2],
        '2 | %s | %s | %s |' % gameboard[3:5],
        '3 | %s | %s | %s |' % gameboard[6:8],
    ])
    return '%s%s' % (res, linesep)

def drawBoard(gameboard):
    print getBoard(gameboard)

def writeFinal(gameboard, filename):
    open(filename, 'w').write(getBoard(gameboard))
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to pass the file handle to be written to as a parameter to `drawBoard` and print to that:

```
def drawBoard(gameboard, outfile=sys.stdout):
    print("    " "a" "   " "b" "   " "c", file=outfile)
    print("  ""-------------", file=outfile)
    print(("1"),("|"),gameboard[0],"|",gameboard[1], "|" ,gameboard[2], "|", file=outfile)
    print("  ""-------------", file=outfile)
    print(("2"),("|"),gameboard[3],"|",gameboard[4], "|" ,gameboard[5], "|", file=outfile)
    print("  ""-------------", file=outfile)   
    print(("3"),("|"),gameboard[6],"|",gameboard[7], "|" ,gameboard[8], "|", file=outfile)
    print("  ""-------------", file=outfile)

with open('/tmp/foo', 'w') as output_file:
    drawBoard(gameboard, output_file)
```

This version defaults to printing to the screen but can easily print to any other writeable file-like object.